# When pushing to next controller the animation shows black tabbar before disappear

Tags: swift, tabbar, pushviewcontroller

I use the following code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

And when pushing to next controller I can see the next bug (black background instead white):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sloye.jpg)

How I can change black background to white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with the next code:

```
tabBarController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
```